# Wrong email after failed gmail login on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, login

My stepmother was using her Windows 10 machine today, and accidentally attempted to log in to her gmail account with (name)@gmail.xom instead of (name)@gmail.com.  The interface will not allow me to change the email back to the appropriate extension, and therefore get in.

What are our options for this?

Comment: Is there an option to switch users? Otherwise you could try doing a hard restart of the PC

Comment: No, there is no option to switch users.  Hard restart simply takes me back to the login screen where the .xom address is displayed.